# Dot product between sum and difference between two vectors.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vectors

The solution to a problem I was working on had the following manipulation that I cannot understand:

(A + B) · (A − B) = A · A − B · B , where A and B are vectors

Could someone please explain the steps in the simplification?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming $\cdot $ is the dot product, if $A,B$ are vectors, then

$$\begin{align} (A+B) \cdot (A-B) & = A \cdot(A-B) + B \cdot (A-B)
\\ & = A \cdot A - A \cdot B + B \cdot A - B \cdot B 
\\ & = A \cdot A - B \cdot B
\end{align}$$

Since $A \cdot B = B \cdot A $